# initialize() method not defined

Tags: javascript, salesforce, apex-code, visualforce

I have a vf page that is using google maps api.  I have a simple apex controller that has a remote action method  using JS remoting.

If I run the page from an account and pass in the accountId to the standardController the page pulls up and displays the google map with the marker location for that account.

If I open the page directly without passing in the accountId, the page pulls up but doesn't display the map and I get two script errors:

syntax error at:
var lat = ;

ReferenceError: initialize is not defined
intitialize();

I can't identify what is causing the error.  Can anyone help?

Here is my controller:

```
public with sharing class AccountMapControllerExtension {

public Account account {get; set;}

public AccountMapControllerExtension(ApexPages.StandardController stdController) {
    if(ApexPages.currentPage().getParameters().get('id') != null) {
        account = [select Id, Name, Geolocation__Latitude__s, Geolocation__Longitude__s, BillingStreet, BillingCity, BillingState, BillingPostalCode, BillingCountry from Account where id =: ApexPages.currentPage().getParameters().get('id')];
    }
}

@RemoteAction
public static List<Account> getNearbyAccounts(Decimal latitude, Decimal longitude) {
    String q = 'select Id, Name, Geolocation__Latitude__s, Geolocation__Longitude__s, BillingStreet, BillingCity, BillingCountry, BillingState, BillingPostalCode from Account ';
    q += 'where DISTANCE(Geolocation__c, GEOLOCATION( ';
    q += String.valueOf(latitude) + ', ' + String.valueOf(longitude);
    q += ' ), \'km\') < 500';

    return Database.query(q);      
}  
}
```

Here is the VF page:

```
<apex:page standardController="Account" extensions="AccountMapControllerExtension" doctype="html-5.0" >
<apex:sectionHeader title="Map of Nearby Accounts"/>
<title>Account Map</title>

<head>
    <!-- STYLE SHEETS  -->
    <apex:stylesheet value="{!URLFOR ($Resource.jQueryUI, '/css/ui-lightness/jquery-ui-1.9.0.custom.css')}" />

</head>
<style>    

    .urlLinks {

        color: blue;
        text-decoration:underline

    }


    #map {
        font-family: Arial;
        font-size:12px;
        line-height:normal !important;
        height:400px;        
        padding: 20px;
    }       
    .roundCornerCss{ 
        /* outer shadows  (note the rgba is red, green, blue, alpha) */
        -webkit-box-shadow: 0px 0px 12px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.4); 
        -moz-box-shadow: 0px 1px 6px rgba(23, 69, 88, .5);

        /* rounded corners */
        -webkit-border-radius: 12px;
        -moz-border-radius: 7px; 
        border-radius: 7px;

        /* gradients */
        background: -webkit-gradient(linear, left top, left bottom, 
        color-stop(0%, white), color-stop(15%, white), color-stop(100%, #D7E9F5)); 
        background: -moz-linear-gradient(top, white 0%, white 55%, #D5E4F3 130%); 
    }   

    #loadingScreen {
        background: url({!URLFOR($Resource.Markers, 'Markers/ajax-loader.gif')}) no-repeat 5px 8px;
        padding-left: 50px;
    }

    /* hide the close x on the loading screen */
    .loadingScreenWindow .ui-dialog-titlebar-close {
        display: none;
    }

</style>
<body>
<apex:includeScript value="{!URLFOR($Resource.jQueryUI, '/js/jquery-1.8.2.min.js')}"/>  
<apex:includeScript value="{!URLFOR($Resource.jQueryUI, '/js/jquery-1.8.2.js')}"/>
<apex:includeScript value="{!URLFOR($Resource.jQueryUI, '/js/jquery-ui-1.9.0.custom.js')}"/>      
<script type="text/javascript"
    src="https://maps.google.com/maps/api/js?sensor=false">
</script>
<script type="text/javascript">

// Global Variables

var geocoder;
var map;
var infowindow = new google.maps.InfoWindow();
var places = [];
var title_content = new Array();                    
var popup_content = new Array();                    
var address = new Array();
var address_position = 0;                    
var timeout = 600;
var pendingCalls = {};  

var markersArray = [];

$j = $.noConflict(); // No Conflict Custom $j


// Initialize

$j(document).ready(function(){

    regDialogs();

});

// Load Google Map

function initialize() {

        geocoder = new google.maps.Geocoder();
        var latlng = new google.maps.LatLng(42.3583, -71.0603); // Boston, MA as Center
        var myOptions = {
          zoom: 3,
          center: latlng,
          mapTypeId: 'roadmap'
        } 

        map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById("map"), myOptions);
}

function regDialogs(){

    $j( "#pendDiv" ).dialog({
        autoOpen: false,
        title: 'Pending Call Reports'
    });

    $j("#loadingScreen").dialog({
        autoOpen: false,    // set this to false so we can manually open it
        dialogClass: "loadingScreenWindow",
        closeOnEscape: false,
        draggable: false,
        width: 460,
        minHeight: 50,
        modal: true,
        buttons: {},
        resizable: false,
        open: function() {
            // scrollbar fix for IE
            $j('body').css('overflow','hidden');
        },
        close: function() {
            // reset overflow
            $j('body').css('overflow','auto');
        }
    }); // end of dialog


    $j("#selectOption").change(function(){

        if($j("select option:selected").text() == 'CUSTOM RANGE'){

            var dates = '<br/>Select Date range: <input type="text" id="startDate"/> &nbsp; to &nbsp;<input type="text" id="endDate"/>';
            $j('#rangeDiv').append(dates);
            regDateHandlers();

        }else {

            $j('#rangeDiv').empty();

        }
    });     
}

// Custom Date popups JQUERY UI

function regDateHandlers(){

    $j(function() {
        $j( "#startDate" ).datepicker({dateFormat: "yy-mm-dd"});
    });

    $j(function() {
        $j( "#endDate" ).datepicker({dateFormat: "yy-mm-dd"});
    });

}


// Waiting Dialog on Loading
function waitingDialog() {

    $j("#loadingScreen").html('<p>Please Wait ...</p>');
    $j("#loadingScreen").dialog('option', 'title', 'Loading');
    $j("#loadingScreen").dialog('open');

}
// Close Waiting Dialog
function closeWaitingDialog() {
    $j("#loadingScreen").dialog('close');

}

function getCurrentAccountMap() {
    var billingStreet = '{!account.BillingStreet}';
    var billingCity = '{!account.BillingCity}';
    var billingState = '{!account.BillingState}';
    var billingCountry = '{!account.BillingCountry}';
    var billingPostalCode = '{!account.BillingPostalCode}';
    address_position = 0;

    $j("#messages").empty();

    clearOverlay(); // Remove existing markers if any

    var addr = billingStreet + ',' + billingCity + ',' + 
                billingState + ',' + billingCountry + ',' + 
                billingPostalCode; 

   address.push(addr);      
   addMarker(address_position);
}

/*

    Main method that gets the Accounts and Call Records for the Selected Date Range.

*/

function getAccountsNearbyMap(){

    waitingDialog(); // Start Loading
    var lat = {!account.Geolocation__Latitude__s};
    var lng = {!account.Geolocation__Longitude__s}; 

    /* Uses JS Remoting to get the Accounts for the Selected Date Range, with Call Reports only*/

    AccountMapControllerExtension.getNearbyAccounts(lat,lng,function(result,event){

        $j("#messages").empty();

        clearOverlay(); // Remove existing markers if any

        if(event.type == 'exception'){
                alert('Error ' + event.message);
        }else {

            address = new Array();
            address_position = 0;
            var completeDate = '';
            var pendClick = '';
            var hasCallRecords = false;

            $j.each(result,function(rec){
                var addr = result[rec].BillingStreet  + ',' + result[rec].BillingCity    + ',' + 
                                   result[rec].BillingState   + ',' + result[rec].BillingCountry + ',' + 
                                   result[rec].BillingPostalCode; 
                address.push(addr); 
            });

            if(address.length > 0){
                addMarker(address_position); // Add the markers based on the Date Range Selected
            }else{
                $j("#messages").append('<h3 style="color:red;">No Accounts with Call Records Found for this Date Range</h3><br/>');
                closeWaitingDialog();
                return false;

            }
        }

    });

  }

  /*Open the Dialog with the Call Reports that are not completed.*/

  function openDialog(clicked){

    $j("#pendDiv").empty();

    var clickedId = clicked.id;

    var pendingCS = '';

    $j.each(pendingCalls[clickedId],function(c){
        pendingCS += '<a href="/'+pendingCalls[clickedId][c].CallId+'" target="_blank" class="urlLinks">' + pendingCalls[clickedId][c].Call + "</a><br/>";
    });

    $j("#pendDiv").append(pendingCS);

    $j("#pendDiv").dialog( "open" );

  }

  /* Add Markers Dynamically */

  function addMarker(position){
        geocoder.geocode({'address': address[position]}, function(results, status){
            if (status == google.maps.GeocoderStatus.OK) {
                places[position] = results[0].geometry.location;                                    
                var marker = new google.maps.Marker({
                    position: places[position],
                    title:title_content[position],
                    icon: getMapIconUrl(position),
                    map: map
                });
                markersArray.push(marker);
                google.maps.event.addListener(marker, 'click', function() {
                    if (!infowindow) {
                        infowindow = new google.maps.InfoWindow({maxWidth: 200});
                    }
                    infowindow.setContent(popup_content[position]);
                    infowindow.open(map, marker);
                });


            }
            else{
                if (status == google.maps.GeocoderStatus.OVER_QUERY_LIMIT){
                    setTimeout(function() { addMarker(position); }, (timeout * 3));
                }
            }
            address_position++;
            if (address_position < address.length){
                setTimeout(function() { addMarker(address_position); }, (timeout));
            }
            closeWaitingDialog();

        });
    }

    function clearOverlay(){

        for (var i = 0; i < markersArray.length; i++ ) {
            markersArray[i].setMap(null);
        }

    }

    /*
       Sets the Marker Type/Color based on the Marker if Pending or Complete
    */

    function getMapIconUrl(markerNumber){

        var mapIconUrl = "{!URLFOR($Resource.Markers, 'Markers/GreenPin.png')}";

        if(String(popup_content[markerNumber]).indexOf('Pending') !== -1)
             mapIconUrl = "{!URLFOR($Resource.Markers, 'Markers/PinkPin.png')}";

        return mapIconUrl;
    }
    window.onload = function() {
        getCurrentAccountMap();
    };
 </script>
 <!-- HTML Content -->
 <div id="inputDiv">
 <select id="selectOption">
    <option value="month">LAST MONTH</option>
    <option value="quarter">LAST QUARTER</option>
    <option value="year">LAST YEAR</option>
    <option value="custom">CUSTOM RANGE</option>
</select><br/>
<div id="rangeDiv"></div><br/>
<input type="button" onclick="getAccountsNearbyMap();" class="btn" value="Submit"/>
  </div><br/><br/>

 <div id="messages"></div><br/>

 <div id="map" class="roundCornerCss"></div>

<script>
       initialize();
</script>

<div id="canvas_div"></div>
<div id="pendDiv"></div>        
<div id="loadingScreen"></div>  
</body>
</apex:page>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ok, this is your issue.

```
var lat = {!account.Geolocation__Latitude__s};
var lng = {!account.Geolocation__Longitude__s};
```

This is not a valid JS statement. In JS, `{}` means a map which expects a `key:value` arrangement. In your case there is nothing like that happening. If you are planning to assign the value of `!account.Geolocation__Latitude__s` to `lat` then you must remove the parenthesis {} from both the statements and then try.

Comment: that is how you reference apex methods and properties in a vf page.  Also, why does it work if I pass in the accountId?

Comment: Not just any Account. I assume that you have a value for Geolocation__Latitude__s and Geolocation__Longitude__s on the Account you are passing? If you pass an Account with these values as empty, you should see the same error.

Answer (score 0):

This is your issue, correct:

```
var lat = {!account.Geolocation__Latitude__s};
var lng = {!account.Geolocation__Longitude__s};
```

Visualforce builds the HTML document before it is loaded into the browser. When you have no value for either `Geolocation__Latitude__s` or `Geolocation__Longitude__s`, then the browser's Javascript engine sees the following

```
var lat = ;
var lng = ;
```

and errors out. You already have a controller extension; create new methods for the Latitude and Longitude values that will return a default value, something like

```
public Integer getLatitude() {
  if (account.Id <> null) {
    if (account.Geolocation__Latitude__s <> null) {
      return account.Geolocation__Latitude__s;
    }
  }
  // default value
  return 0.0;
}
```

and called via

```
var lat = {!latitude};
```